# search an item in a array

Tags: java

i have the String str="abc"; and i want to search if there is the letter "b" in it.I convert it to char[] and i create a for loop.this is my code [code]

```
      String str="abc";
      char c[] = str.toCharArray();

      for(int k=1;k<c.length;k++){
          if(c[k]=='b')
                {  
                System.out.println("yes");
                }
          else {
            System.out.println("no");}
                }
```

why does it print 'no'??

Comment: According to your code it must print `yes \n no` since you starts from 1 (not from zero)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do `str.contains("b")`.

In terms of your code, your `k` should be initialised to 0. The following code prints:

> no
>   yes
>   no

```
String str = "abc";
char c[] = str.toCharArray();

for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
    if (c[k] == 'b') {
        System.out.println("yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```

A more conventional way to do it might be this:

```
public boolean contains( String strToCheck, char strContent ) {
    // return strToCheck.contains(strContent);

    for( int i = 0; i < strToCheck.length(); i++ ) {
        if( strToCheck.charAt(i) == strContent ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This would stop checking as soon as it finds the character. But really it is better to use the built-in API.

Comment: also, if you additional want to find the position of 'b', you can do str.indexOf('b');

Comment: thanks for your answer!can i find how many times the "b" appears in the string?

Comment: the given code starts iteration from `k=1` and hence prints `yes no` :)

Comment: yes, just assign a integer variable to zero and add one to it every time you print an "yes", and you will get the count.

Comment: @Sanjay, I modified the code to use 0 in the snippet I posted.

Comment: @des, To count occurrence, you could use the commons lang library from Apache and simply do `StringUtils.countMatches("abc", "b");`

Comment: @Mike Kwan it gives me a message cannot find symbol:countMatches

Answer (score 1):

if you find your search key you should just stop looking.

and it is not necessary that on first iteration you will find your key

```
  String str="abc";
  char charArr[] = str.toCharArray();
  boolean found = false;

  for(char char: charArr){
      if(char =='b')
            {  
             found = true;
             break;
            }

    }

    if(found){  */Say Found*/ }else{/*Say no*/}
```

or simply

```
   stringInstance.contains("b");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simpler way.

```
    String str1 = "abc";
    if(str1.contains("b")){
        System.out.println("i am here");
    }else{
        System.out.println("none");
    }
```

String class provides this method to search for any string in it .

If you want to use your code only then you can just modify it a little bit by adding a "break" statement.

```
      String str="abc";
      char c[] = str.toCharArray();

      for(int k=0;k<c.length;k++){
          if(c[k]=='b')
                {  
                System.out.println("yes");
                break;
                }
          else {
            System.out.println("no");}
                }

        }
```

Comment: This would keep printing `no` till the char was found though.

Comment: Exactly Mike. I just tried to modify his code to print "yes" if the char is there . That is the reason I din't pay attention on the else part . Thanks for pointing that out .